# Need Assistance with PowerShell using Import-Excel Module

Tags: excel, powershell, export-to-excel

The attached code creates an excel file that and adds formatting.  It's also supposed to load the data from the first two columns to the first two rows.   The area I am having issues with this Section.

```
    For($i=4;$i -ge $count;$++){
        $cv = $Sheet.Cells[$($i-1),1].Value
        $Sheet.Cells[1,$i].value = $cv
        $cv = $sheet.Cells[$($i-1),2].value
        $Sheet.Cells[2,$i].value = $cv
    }
```

This is suppose to take the data from col A & B for the rows 3..8 and put the data into rows 1 & 2 col D:I.  So the data going down is the same as going across.

If I don't run the Close-ExcelPackage statement it shows that the data correct information is set but after closing the package the data is not in the spreadsheet.

I can do it with a formula but then the column widths are 0 and therefore hidden.

Sample code:

```
remove-item -path $prnfn -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
Write-host -f Green "Create base Excel file"
$xl = $file|Export-Excel -WorkSheetName $wsn -ClearSheet -PassThru -Path $prnfn -StartRow 2 -FreezePane 3,3 -AutoSize
Write-host -f Green "Assign Worksheet name"
$sheet = $xl.Workbook.Worksheets[$wsn]
Write-host -f Green "Set formats and formulas"
For($i=4;$i -ge $count;$++){
    $cv = $Sheet.Cells[$($i-1),1].Value
    $Sheet.Cells[1,$i].value = $cv
    $cv = $sheet.Cells[$($i-1),2].value
    $Sheet.Cells[2,$i].value = $cv
}
Set-Format -Worksheet $sheet -Range "A:A" -HorizontalAlignment Left
$rng="D1:"+$c[$($count+3)]+"1"
#Set-ExcelRange -Worksheet $xl.$Sheet -Range $rng -Formula '=INDIRECT("A"&COLUMN()-1)' -HorizontalAlignment Left 
$rng="D2:"+$c[$($count+3)]+"2"
#Set-ExcelRange -Worksheet $xl.$Sheet -Range $rng -Formula '=INDIRECT("B"&COLUMN()-1)' -HorizontalAlignment Left 
$rng="C:"+$c[$($count+3)]
Set-format -worksheet $sheet -Range $rng -NumberFormat '#,##0'

Write-host -f Green "Complete Excel process"
Close-ExcelPackage $xl -Calculate
```

***Header row starts on row 2***

| Keycode | Description | Net Input | list1 | list2 | list3 | list4 | list5 | list6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SUPPRESS | SUPPRESS | 16,006 | 1 | 236 | 113 | 120 | 421 | 8 |
| 423A | Test 23 buyers 45+ | 9,062 | 0 | 8 | 360 | 345 | 8,841 | 1,977 |
| 423B | Test 23 buyers 25-45 | 4,178 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 184 | 3,706 | 349 |
| 423C | Test 23 buyers < 25 | 3,655 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 3,006 | 120 |
| 423D | Test 23 buyers | 15,974 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 422A | Test 22 buyers 45+ | 8,485 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

**What I need it to look like is**

|  |  |  | SUPPRESS | 423A | 423B | 423C | 423D | 422A |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Keycode | Description | Net Input | SUPPRESS | Test 23 buyers 45+ | Test 23 buyers 25-45 | Test 23 buyers < 25 | Test 23 buyers | Test 22 buyers 45+ |
| SUPPRESS | SUPPRESS | 16,006 | 1 | 236 | 113 | 120 | 421 | 8 |
| 423A | Test 23 buyers 45+ | 9,062 | 0 | 8 | 360 | 345 | 8,841 | 1,977 |
| 423B | Test 23 buyers 25-45 | 4,178 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 184 | 3,706 | 349 |
| 423C | Test 23 buyers < 25 | 3,655 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 3,006 | 120 |
| 423D | Test 23 buyers | 15,974 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 422A | Test 22 buyers 45+ | 8,485 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |